# Use input parameter in form

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dialog in which I have a form. To the form component I pass an object of type `User`. I want to use that object in the fields of the form. Meaning that when the form is opened (this happens after a click in which we also pass the object) the fields of the form will be populated with the values from the object. Also when I first construct the form component I make an ajax call to get some `Role` objects and use them to construct a dropdown select. I want the selected option of that dropdown to be the passed user's object role.

```
@Component({
  inputs: ['selectedUser'],
  outputs: ['editedUser'],
  selector: 'user-form',
  templateurl: 'user.form.themplate.html'
})
export class UserForm {

// user object has login , firstName, lastName, email and role properties
selectedUser: User;    
roles: Role[];    
controlForm: FormGroup;
editedUser: EventEmitter<User>

loginControl: AbstractControl;
firstNameControl: AbstractControl;
lastNameControl: AbstractControl;
roleControl: AbstractControl;
emailControl: AbstractControl;

constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
   this.controlForm = fb.group({
      'loginControl': ['', Validators.required],
      'firstNameControl': ['', Validators.required],
      'lastNameControl': ['', Validators.required],
      'roleControl': ['', Validators.required],
      'emailControl': ['', Validators.compose(Validators.required, 
                                          MailValidator.validateMail]});

   this.loginControl= this.myForm.controls['loginControl'];
   this.firstNameControl= this.myForm.controls['firstNameControl'];
   this.lastNameControl= this.myForm.controls['lastNameControl'];
   this.emailControl= this.myForm.controls['emailControl'];
   this.roleControl= this.myForm.controls['roleControl'];

    // somehow fill this.roles with Role object
 });

 onSave() :void {
    // or get the object from controlForm.value
    // and send that one
    this.editedUser.emit(this.selectedUser);
 }
}
```

---

```
 <form [formGroup]="controlForm">
 <div class="field">
   <input type="text"
      [formControl]="loginContol">
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <input type="text"
      [formControl]="firstNameControl">
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <input type="text"
      [formControl]="lastNameContol">
 </div>
 <div class="field">
   <input type="text"
      [formControl]="emailContol">
 </div>

<select [formControl]="roleContol">
  <option *ngFor="let r of roles"
      [selected] = "some expression to select the role from the selectedUser object"
   >{{r.name}}</option>
</select>
 <button type="save" [disabled]="!controlForm.valid" (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
 </form>
```

What I want is when the form is showed all its fields to be populated with the data from the `selectedUser` object, this includes the role from the dropdown if the user has a role. After that when the `save` button is clicked I wan't to use the data that was in the form (only some fileds may have been changed) and send that data in the form of a `User` object to the event emitter. I saw that you can use `ngModel` and `ngForm` instead, but that doesn't seem the better aproach to me and also I don't know how the validators assignment works there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two way binding if you want to bind the user attributes to the form inputs and also want to submit the changed user info elsewhere on save:

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control" id="name" required
   [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.name" name="name">
```

This way if anyone changes the name input when you access your `selectedUser` in `onSave()` method you will have the updated info.

You can put as much validation as you want like the `required` which is used in there.

For more info on forms take a look at [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can bind one-way and tow-way binding both in form asbelow:

- Form which pass parameter to other form:

**One-Way Binding:**

```
<widget [myName]="model.Name"></widget>
```

**Two-Way Binding:**

```
<widget [(myName)]="model.Name"></widget>
```

- Form which accept input parameter:

  `import {Input} from "@angular/core";
  @Component({
    selector: 'widget',
    templateUrl:'content/Widget.html'
  })

  export class Widget {
     @Input() myName: string= "";
  }`